# How can we save darts model lets say TFT Model using mlflow

Tags: time-series, databricks, mlflow, u8darts

I want to save my Darts TFT MODEL using mlflow and load it using mlflow. Currently i log my model using sklearn flavor not i am unable to load it.
ERROR - (AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute '_accelerator_connector')

Currently i log my model using sklearn flavor not i am unable to load it.
When i tried to load model using mlflow.sklearn.load_model() it is giving error
ERROR - (AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute '_accelerator_connector')

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks